# Hibernate @OneToMany how to persist the relationship without updating the (many) elements?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have

```
public class Stale {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "stale", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Poney> poneys;
}
```

and

```
public class Poney {

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "stale_id")
    private Stale stale;

    private String name;
}
```

When I try to save a stale with an updated poney list, **the persisting of a stale** doesn't behave like I would it to do.

- [GOOD] added poneys (existing in te db) are well persisted as stale members
- [BAD] poneys removed from the stable are still in the stable after save(). Caution : I want them removed from the stable but I don't want to kill any pony from the db !
- [BAD] if the poney's name is edited before persisting the stale, the name modification is persisted. But **I would like to persist only the relationship**, not poney modifications.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Your first [BAD} sounds like it might be fixed by setting `orphanRemoval = true` on the `@OneToMany` mapping. And I don't understand the second point?

Comment: @Deltharis sorry my point wasn't clear, I edited it. I think orphanRemoval = true would kill every poney when deleting a stable isn't it ?

Comment: orphanRemoval would kill any pony you remove from stable. Buut note that you did add CascadeType.ALL, which should kill poneys when removing a stable by itself anyway (since it will cascade the DELETE operation), orphanRemoval will just also kill them when you just remove them (making it a composition instead of aggregation)

Comment: Indeed, `CascadeType.ALL` implies `DELETE` but not nécessarily `orphanRemoval` because the `oneToMany` relation between Stale and Poneys is not necessarely a composition. Without more hint, Poneys may exist without being linked to a stale. But `orphanRemoval=true` will do the trick if you remove the poneys from the poneys list of a stale. Be careful to remove it from the existing list and avoid replacing this list by new one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this is a bi-directional relationship. When updating the state of a bidirectional relationship it is applications duty to update the state on both sides (so not only remove Ponies from Stable, but also remove the Stable reference in Ponies). That can be accomplished for example by `@BeforePersist` or `@BeforeUpdate` method in the Stable entity. Since Pony is the owner of the relationship JPA sees the state of Pony as more important than state of Stable, and removing ponies in Stable does nothing.

As for your last point - again, since this is bidirectional and Pony is the owner it's impossible to change the state of the relationship without saving new state of Pony (including any changes like name).

They way you want this to behave makes me think what you actually want is a uni-directional relationship on the Stable side:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="stale_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private List<Poney> poneys;
```

And removing the @ManyToOne mapping in Pony.